# Replicating Sublime3's Monokai Color Scheme to Jupyter Notebooks

Tags: colors, themes, sublimetext3, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to replicate Sublime's Monokai color scheme for my Jupyter notebooks (in Ubuntu) and I used [jupyterthemes](https://github.com/dunovank/jupyter-themes) but it is not the same theme. Is there an easy way to replicate Sublime's Monokai color scheme for Jupyter?
If not, how can I make equal (and other operators) red?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add the [Stylus](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylus/clngdbkpkpeebahjckkjfobafhncgmne?utm_source=chrome-ntp-icon) addon to your browser and create a style that applies to `http://localhost:` by copying the content `monokai.css` from [here](https://github.com/dunovank/jupyter-themes/blob/master/jupyterthemes/styles/compiled/monokai.css).